# Unable to process boost asio:- async read buffer's callback asynchronously

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm using boost::asio::async_read() method to asynchronously get response from server which take 10 second to process request. I am able to read response successfully. but I am attaching callback to this function to process received response which take 10 seconds. I am unable to find how i can process that callback asynchronously.

```
void read_response(std::string data)
{
    cout << data << endl;
    sleep(10);
    // if you think sleep works differently if i send another rest api request from here still this function blocks the processing
}
boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), [&](const boost::system::error_code&
                                                                     error,
                                                                 std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    io_context.post([&]() {
        read_response(buffer.data());
        //read_response is not processing asynchronously
    });
});
```

I tried posting function to io_context, i tried using

```
std::async(std::launch::deferred, read_handler,error,bytes_transferred,buffer.data()).wait() ;
```

I am new to asyn programming and c++ programming.

Comment: Sleeping in the callback is going to certainly be an issue. Where is the code that issues the next read?

Comment: I'm guessing your `io_context` doesn't have multiple threads? If you have blocking code in code running inside `io_context` it wont be able to do anything else. `std::async(...).wait()` is pretty pointless, it won't help

Comment: I think you have a good question, but there are not enough details on how you are doing things. I haven't done `asio` work in about 6 years or so, but I remember that you had to "chain" your calls to avoid having everything grind to a halt.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, don't do blocking operations on the IO service. **Or** grow the thread pool to accomodate for the maximum number of concurrent tasks that must be supported.

In **all** circumstances, copy the message into your read handler, instead of passing the buffer directly (as you did) as that invites race conditions/stale references.

Let's demonstrate using [httpbin.org/delay](https://httpbin.org/#/Dynamic_data/get_delay__delay_):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0ce1512bef3dc49)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::string const request = "GET /delay/10 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\n\r\n";

void read_response(std::string data) {
    std::cout << "Asynchronously received response: " << quoted(data) << std::endl;
    sleep(10);
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context  ioc(1);
    asio::thread_pool work(10); // support 10 tasks along-side async IO

    tcp::socket conn(ioc);
    connect(conn, tcp::resolver(ioc).resolve("httpbin.org", "80"));
    write(conn, asio::buffer(request));

    std::string buf;
    async_read_until( //
        conn, asio::dynamic_buffer(buf), "\r\n\r\n",
        [&work, &buf](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t n) {
            std::cout << "\n*** Completion " << ec.message() << ", " << n << std::endl;

            post(work, [msg = buf.substr(0, n)] {
                // NOTE: lambda owns msg, not a reference to `buf`
                read_response(std::move(msg));
            });
        });

    std::thread([&ioc] {
        ioc.run();
        std::cout << "\n*** IO complete" << std::endl;
    }).detach();

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

    work.join();
    std::cout << "\n*** Work Done" << std::endl;
}
```

This shows work continuing, "asynchronously" (relative to IO) well after `ioc` completes:

[image]